# Find the maximum value associated with a specific value in a different column

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, worksheet-function, array-formulas

I need to find the largest value in column B associated with a specific value in column A.
Here's an example of what I mean:

```
A      B

2       1
2      14
2      22
5       6
5       8
5      99
```

I.e. I want to find the the largest value, `22`, in column B on the same row as a `2` in column A.

I'm currently using this to try find the value, however it only finds the first value:

```
 =VLOOKUP(A2, A1:B20, 2, FALSE)
```

Comment: Does 22 qualify because it's a multiple of 2? or because it only contains the number "2" ?

Comment: I just want a command that finds the largest number in column b that is associated with a value in column A.  So if we took the value 5 in column A, I want a function which returns the value 99 as the largest value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=MAX(IF(A:A=2,B:B))
```

entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.